# How to change font size in a textview?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am making an application were user can read a detail or text and user can also be able to change the font size as per there requirement?

i hd tried using the following code but it's not working

```
-(IBAction)textSizeAction:(id)sender
{
    [self setText:[self text] withSize:[sender floatValue]];        
}
```

so please suggest me some tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

You try with setFont method...

```
[urTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"urFont/Helvetica" size:[sender floatValue]]];
```

//add Your font type